# Recycle disappear when switching between fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have four fragments inside DashboardActvity. I have recycle view in HomeFragment and it is the default page loading first up. Recycle view appear first time but when I switch to another fragment and come again to HomeFragment it disappear.
Here is my DashbaordActivity.

```
public class DashboardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // views
    private BottomNavigationView bottomNav;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

        bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav);

        bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(bottomNavMethod);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new HomeFragment()).commit() ;

    }

    // click event listener
    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener bottomNavMethod =
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    Fragment fragment =null;
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.home:
                            fragment = new HomeFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.chat:
                            fragment = new ChatFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.map:
                            fragment = new MapsFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.users:
                            fragment = new UserFragment();
                            break;
                    }
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
                    return true;
                }
            };
}
```

Here is my HomeFragment

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    // views
    private View homeView;
    private RecyclerView childList;
    private Adapter adapter;

    // variables
    private IAPI api;
    private CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
    private SharedPreferences preferences;
    private List<Child> cList = new ArrayList<>();
    private Integer image = R.drawable.avatar;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        homeView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        preferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(Constatnt.MY_PREFERENCE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        api = RetrofitClient.getInstance().create(IAPI.class);
        childList = homeView.findViewById(R.id.child_rec_view);

        adapter = new Adapter(getContext(), cList, image);

        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        childList.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        childList.setAdapter(adapter);

        return homeView;
    }

    private void getChildren() {
        int parentId = preferences.getInt("Id", 0);

        compositeDisposable.add(api.getChildren(parentId)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe(new Consumer<List<Child>>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(List<Child> children) throws Exception {
                for (Child c:children) {
                    cList.add(c);
                }
            }
        }));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        getChildren();
    }
}
```

What is the issue and how I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

override

> onViewCreated()

and add set adapter inside this method

```
    childList = view.findViewById(R.id.child_rec_view);
 adapter = new Adapter(getContext(), cList, image);

    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    childList.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
    childList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Not worked then I moved everything to onViewCreated() then it worked for some distance. But the issue remains same